# Edit .csv file via shell script output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I have a script which takes a `.csv` file as a an input and runs row by row

```
kma210,projects.kma210
kma215,projects.kma215_2
KMA3xx,projects.kma3xx
KMI7,projects.kmi7
```

The above one is a sample for the `.csv` file. I have two types of process running for each row (example : abc_process and xyz_process).

Now my requirement is once the script runs one row , the output i.e., success/fail should print in the same file in third column (`abc_process`) and fourth column (`xyz_process`).

Example please see here:

```
kma210,projects.kma210,success,success
kma215,projects.kma215_2,fail,success
KMA3xx,projects.kma3xx,success,fail
KMI7,projects.kmi7,fail,fail
```

Could anyone please suggest?

Comment: How do you receive the status? `success`/`fail`?

Comment: You'll have to check for simultaneous file access

Comment: @Inian i gave echo for the output to see if it's success or failed.

echo "abc_process success"
echo "xyz_process success"

Is there a possibility to parse the echo output and add in third, fourth columns ?

Comment: @SubratSahoo: When do you say, process a row? how are you doing it, using `awk` and running any system commands within or how else?

Comment: @Inian

cat "$1" | while IFS='' read -r line; do
    D="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1 | tr -d '"')"
    P="$(echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2)"
    echo 'D: '"$D"
    echo 'P: '"$P"

Comment: That way, you can always append the statuses to a new file? Is it ok with you? or you need in-place write?

Comment: @SubratSahoo: Another question of mine is how do you generate the string `abc_process success` from the first 2 column values? Do you run an external command to get the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is something of this sort.

From your input file (`input.csv`), use the script as follows:-

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2
do
    # The below two read commands are to process the success/fail status
    # string as you indicated. If you are receiving a string of the below 
    # form, from an external bash command; you need to use process-substitution 
    # as

    # IFS= read -r _ p1Status <<(p1Command)
    # IFS= read -r _ p1Status <<(p2Command)

    IFS= read -r _ p1Status <<<"abc success"
    IFS= read -r _ p2Status <<<"xyz fail"

    # The below printf just prints the output as you need to stdout
    # to create a .csv out of it, append it to a new file as

    # printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$p1Status" "$p2Status" >> output.csv

    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$p1Status" "$p2Status"
done<input.csv
```

The above command as such writing to `stdout`, produces an output as

```
kma210,projects.kma210,success,fail
kma215,projects.kma215_2,success,fail
KMA3xx,projects.kma3xx,success,fail
KMI7,projects.kmi7,success,fail
```

which you can append to a file using the `>>` operator with the line I commented out. Or if you want a single file and replace the original file. Add a line

```
mv -v output.csv input.csv
```

as the last line of the script.

Comment: i am a rookie in scripting, i will give my script here. could you please incorporate the same into it ?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, you have to make an attempt to improvise from the solution I have already provided. You can post your requirement, let me see how can I help you.